# C# LINQ generates "Specified cast is not valid" error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, datatable

I am using the following code to do a left outer join between two tables; one from SQL and one from MySQL. Basically, I want to take the resultant SQL datatable, add a column to it, and if there is a row with matching UserID in the MySQL datatable, add the value to the new column in the SQL datatable for the matching record.

```
var dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof (int));
dtResult.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof (string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof (int));

var result = from sqlDataRows in sqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    join mySqlDataRows in mySqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    on sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID") equals Convert.ToInt32(mySqlDataRows.Field<string>("SiteUserID")) into lj
    from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID"),
        sqlDataRows.Field<string>("Field1"),
        r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("Field2")
    }, false);
```

However, I am getting a "Specified cast is not valid" error on the line that executes "Select dtResult.LoadDataRow". I haven't been able to figure out why and I have triple checked that the data types match.

Comment: BTW I figured out that the reason it wasn't able to cast the data was because, behind the scenes, "Field2" is a MySQL Count() function, which returns LONG data type, not INT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `select` is an IEnumerable. You would need to then `LoadDataRow` on each resulting item - you can't do it inline as you're trying to do.

For example, something like:

```
var result = from sqlDataRows in sqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
  join mySqlDataRows in mySqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
  on sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID") equals Convert.ToInt32(mySqlDataRows.Field<string>("SiteUserID")) into lj
  from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new object[] 
  {
    sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID"),
    sqlDataRows.Field<string>("Field1"),
    r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("Field2")
  };

foreach (var item in result)
{
  dtResult.LoadDataRow(item, false);
}
```

This process is called "projection", and you can shape the resulting object however you want. However, you're going to get an object back for each record in the query. How you use it from there is up to you.

I've never done a cross-database (cross-system) join like this, so whether the framework even lets you do this may be your next hurdle.